# How do I make the proxy work? Python requests

Tags: python, web, redirect, proxy, python-requests

```
import requests

http_proxy = "http://176.9.119.170:8080"

proxyDict = {
  "http": http_proxy,
}
url = 'http://2ip.ru'
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxyDict
r = s.get(url)
print(r.text, r.url, r.headers)
```

This code give "requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects." error.

Also, I previously tried to use a proxy in selenium, but there was a similar error. Moreover, even with working proxies(which was confirmed by checkers)

Comment: `http://2ip.ru` redirects you to `https://2ip.ru/`, but you've set proxy only for `http` protocol. You should add `https` key to your `proxyDict` with same value and take a look on your proxy, probably issue with redirects is on proxy side.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i change proxy to https and edit proxyDict. But now it returns " Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)')))"

Comment: You don't need to change value of `http_proxy`, you just need to add one more key to `proxyDict` with same value so it will look like: `proxyDict = dict.fromkeys(("http", "https"), http_proxy)`. And again, check your proxy, 99% issue is in proxy.

Comment: Maybe there is some way to use http? I can't find normal free https proxies.

Comment: There's no http version of this particular website, maybe you can find another with similar functionality which allows you to work via http protocol.

Comment: This site was only needed to check the proxy's performance. The thing is, I need to apply a proxy for avito.ru, but there seems to be no http version as on 2ip.ru

Answer (score 0):

Correct code to this form:

```
import requests

http_proxy = "http://176.9.119.170:8080"

proxyDict = {
  "http": http_proxy,
}
url = 'http://2ip.ru'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)
print(r.text, r.url, r.headers)
```

Comment: requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects

Comment: This error refers to your url, 'http://2ip.ru' has redirects, it's not the code, code works fine, try other url to check it.

Comment: Still a redirect. Even on Google and any other site

Comment: So it's your http proxy, try with something else

Comment: Maybe you can show a working example with a working proxy? I have already tried with more than a dozen different http proxies that were marked as working on various checkers.